# Google Play Services iOS 's push notifications is not working

Tags: ios, google-play-services

I'm testing Google Play Service in iOS with TBMPSkeleton from `https://github.com/playgameservices/ios-basic-samples`

I did upload all APNS Certificate in Google Play Console ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfS88.png)) but when running game on devices, i didn't receive any notifications when having invitations or when match status changed in both development or production environment. Debugging show that game did receive APNS token successfully, i did test my certificates using php scripts from https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial and sent push notifications successfully.

So what wrong with my project? Did i config something wrong? I'm using XCode 7.3.1 (7D1014), Google Play Service 5.1.1

Answer (score -1):

Check the [Adding Push Notifications in Your iOS Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/notifications).

It's good that you were able to download your APNS certificate. But that's just step 1. The succeeding steps are:

Step 2. Create a provisioning profile that contains push notification entitlements. To learn how to create a provisioning profile, you can refer to the Apple Developer Provisioning and Development documentation, under 'Creating and Installing the Provisioning Profile'. Make sure to drag the provisioning profile to your test device in the organizer.

Step 3. Upload the .p12 file that you created to the Google Play Developer Console. The .p12 file must be in the PKCS #12 format, and must contain only a single certificate.

Step 4. Register your app to receive push notifications after the user successfully signs-in. Add the following code in your finishedWithAuth:error handler, at the point where the user has successfully signed in to Google Play games services. This brings up the standard iOS push notifications dialog. If your game already has registered for push notifications by implementing this code elsewhere, then you don't need to add this line again.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Step 5. In your appDelegate, add the following code to the callback for retrieving the push device token passed back from APNS. This device token is used for outbound push notifications, and your app must register it with the Google Play games services push service. Make sure to always register your device token through GPGManager to enable push notifications from Google Play games services. Even if the user has not signed in; the GPGmanager object will cache this token and save it until the user signs in.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
        :(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Got deviceToken from APNS! %@", deviceToken);
    [[GPGManager sharedInstance] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken
            forEnvironment:GPGPushNotificationEnvironmentSandbox];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, i did follow this document and receive device token successfully, but i can't receive any notifications. Do you have any ideas?